# How do I send email to multiple recipients in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am unable to send email through google script to multiply addresses

Tried with GmailApp.sendEmail,MailApp.SendEmail, var recipient = testmail + chemAmail ;.

```
  var testmail     = "example1@gmail.com" ;
  var chemAmail    = "example2@gmail.com" ;

  var body = "Hi,<br><br>" +
             "This is a Quality Alert.Please brief the required people and submit the Briefing Record EForm when it is completed." + "<br><br>" +
             "The details are stated below :<br>" +
             "Customer: " + customer + "<br>" +
             "Part Number: " + part + "<br>" +
             "S Number: " + s + "<br>" +
             "ID Number: " + id + "<br>" +
             "Defect : " + defect + "<br>" +
             "Description : " + desc + "<br>" +
             "Reject Photos : " + reject + "<br>" +
             "Okay Photos : " + ok + "<br><br>" +
             "Please complete it as soon as possible." + "<br><br>" +
             "Thanks." ;

    // Sends if chemA is ticked (Conditions for email to be sent)
    if(chemA == '✔')
    {
      var recipient = testmail , chemAmail;
      var subject = "Quality Alert for Chem A";
    }

GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, " ",{htmlBody: body});
```

I can send it to testmail only. I want to be able to send to multiple email addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to send a mail to several mail addresses.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var recipient = testmail , chemAmail;
```

#### To:

```
var recipient = [testmail, chemAmail];
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, I'm using above method. But I couldn't find [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body), so if this didn't work in your environment, I apologize.

  - By [TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702702/how-do-i-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-in-google-app-script/55702925?noredirect=1#comment98096135_55702925), I could find the description of `comma separated list of email addresses` at [GmailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body).

    - By this, the array might be converted to the string by the script like `array.join(",")`.

#### Reference:

- [GmailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body)

  - `recipient`: comma separated list of email addresses

Comment: Yup it works! Thanks. I did'nt know that the script would only take the 1st option and ignore the rest after the comma if there was no bracket.

Comment: `MailApp` documentation shows recipients should be a string separated by `,`.  It's probably the same here too. When you provide a array, it converts it into `var rec = testmail+','+chemAmail;`

Comment: @Adrian Peh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. Yes. I proposed this because I thought that from OP's situation, to use an array might be suitable. By the way, I didn't know about the way for using ``,`` in the official document of ``MailApp``. Can you tell me the link about it? I would like to add the link to my answer as a reference.

Comment: @Tanaike  On looking again, even your [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body)  states the same. Type of recipient is `String` and description is stated as `comma separated list of email addresses`. In [mailapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body), `String the addresses of the recipients, separated by commas`. So like ``"recipent1@example.com,recipient2@example.com"``

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I could find it now by the information you provided. I could update my answer. This information might be also useful for other users. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the following:

```
var recipient = testmail + "," + chemAmail;
```

Email recipients need to be comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets did the job for me.

It's set up like this:
`GmailApp.sendEmail([recipientEmail, emailcons],emailSubject,html, {from: alias[1], name:"Consultas Tributarias",htmlBody: html})`

`recipientEmail` is a const, and `emailcons` is the email of the form submitter.

Now both of them get the email upon form submission.

Thanks Tanaike!

Comment: Might want to refer to passing an array for the recipent argument as such instead of "square brackets"